# Hibernate does not create tables but also throws no errors

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

Hibernate does not create any tables:

I got a Tomcat server where my `jsf/hibernate` project runs on. The database server is a `MySQL` server. Starts without problems but does not create any tables.

I made a new project without the Tomcat server and any other stuff. Only the Hibernate related code. Still no errors and warnings, but also no tables created.

**Hibernate config (`hibernate.cfg.xml`):**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/3bt_database</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="model.Testtable"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateUtil**:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionfactory = buildSessionFactory();

    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionfactory(){
        return sessionfactory;
    }
}
```

**StartStopListener**:

```
@WebListener
public class StartStopListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().openSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().close();
    }
}
```

**Testtable**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tblTest")
public class Testtable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int testID;
    private String testname;
}
```

Please do not tell me to create them manually. This is *not* the answer I am looking for.

Comment: which hibernate version you are using ?does your database has password? any console error or warnings ?

Comment: Hibernate 5.2.2. No, for testing i used root and blank on purpose.

Comment: is the package name of `Testtable` class is `model`?

Comment: Creating SessionFactory, changes in version, try this ->  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_obtaining_an_sessionfactory

Comment: try to prepend `hibernate.` in every propery name

Comment: This happens when your entity object is not tied(attached) with any hibernate session. you need to look at how you are saving the object & does that object is attached to any hibernate session?

Comment: Bikku: yes
shantaram: thanks i will take a look at it. you mean in the hibernate config? isnt that irrelevant?
Rohit Gaikwad: sorry i fail to understand what you mean with the last part of the question.

Comment: yes in Hibernate Config file ...

Comment: @shantaram no errors. two warnings, but unrelated

Answer (score 0):

try to prepend **hibernate.** in every propery name

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/3bt_database</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="model.Testtable"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Update :-**
Provide one more property. try at beginning ..

```
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    //or try with
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved the problem. The mapping setting in the XML was no working properly. [This link](https://coderanch.com/t/654369/ORM/databases/Hibernate-Mapping-hibernate-cfg-xml) helped me out very much.